# Cherrypy web server hangs forever -- Matplotlib error

Tags: matplotlib, cherrypy

I'm creating a web-based interface for a number of different command line executables, and am using cherrypy behind apache (using mod_rewrite).  I'm very new to this, and am having difficulty getting things configured properly.  On my development machine, everything works reasonable well, but when I installed the code on a second machine I can't get anything to work properly.

The basic workflow for the applications is: 1. upload a dataset, 2. process the data (using python with some calls to executables using subprocess.call), 3. display the results on the web page.

After uploading and processing one dataset, everytime I attempt to process a second dataset the system stops responding.  I'm not seeing any output in the terminal from the cherrypy process, or in the site log that shows any errors have occurred.

I'm starting cherrypy with the following conf file:

```
[global]
environment: 'production'
log.error_file: 'logs/site.log'
log.screen: True
tools.sessions.on: True
tools.session.storage_type: "file"
tools.session.storage_path: "sessions/"
tools.sessions.timeout: 60
tools.auth.on: True
tools.caching.on: False
server.socket_host: '0.0.0.0'
server.max_request_body_size: 0 
server.socket_timeout: 60
server.thread_pool: 20
server.socket_queue_size: 10

engine.autoreload.on:True
```

My **init**.py file:

```
import cherrypy
import os
import string
from os.path import exists, join
from os import pathsep
from string import split

from mako.template import Template
from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup
from auth import AuthController, require, member_of, name_is

from twopoint import TwoPoint

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
lookup = TemplateLookup(directories=[current_dir + '/templates'])

def findInSubdirectory(filename, subdirectory=''):
  if subdirectory:
    path = subdirectory
  else:
    path = os.getcwd()
  for root, dirs, names in os.walk(path):
      if filename in names:
          return os.path.join(root, filename)
 return None

class Root:
  @cherrypy.expose
  @require()
  def index(self):
      tmpl = lookup.get_template("main.html")
      return tmpl.render(usr=WebUtils.getUserName(),source="")


if __name__=='__main__':
  conf_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
  conf_path = os.path.join(conf_path, "prod.conf")
  cherrypy.config.update(conf_path)
  cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1',
                          'server.socket_port': 8080});

  def nocache():
      cherrypy.response.headers['Cache-Control']='no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate'
      cherrypy.response.headers['Pragma']='no-cache'
      cherrypy.response.headers['Expires']='0'

  cherrypy.tools.nocache = cherrypy.Tool('before_finalize',nocache)
  cherrypy.config.update({'tools.nocache.on':'True'})

  cherrypy.tree.mount(Root(), '/')
  cherrypy.tree.mount(TwoPoint(),       '/twopoint')
  cherrypy.engine.start()
  cherrypy.engine.block()
```

For one example where this occurs, I've got the following javascript function that calls my python code:

```
function compTwoPoint(dataset,orig){
  // call python code to generate images
  $.post("/twopoint/compTwoPoint/"+dataset,
   function(result){
       res=jQuery.parseJSON(result);
       if(res.success==true){
       showTwoPoint(res.path,orig);
       }
       else{
       alert(res.exception);
       $('#display_loading').html("");
       }
   });
}
```

This calls the python code:

```
def twopoint(in_matrix):
   """proprietary code, can't share"""    

def twopoint_file(in_file_name,out_file_name):
    k = imread(in_file_name);
    figure()
    imshow(twopoint(k))
    colorbar()
    savefig(out_file_name,bbox_inches="tight")
    close()

class TwoPoint:

    @cherrypy.expose
    def compTwoPoint(self,dataset):
        try:
            fnames=WebUtils.dataFileNames(dataset)
             twopoint_file(fnames['filepath'],os.path.join(fnames['savebase'],"twopt.png"))

        return encoder.iterencode({"success": True})
```

These functions work together to give the expected result.  The problem is that after processing one input file, I am unable to process a second file.  I don't seem to get a response from the server.

On the machine where things are working, I'm running python 2.7.6 and cherrypy 3.2.3.  On the second machine, I have python 2.7.7 and cherrypy 3.3.0.  While this may explain the difference in behavior, I'd like to find a way to make my code portable enough to overcome the difference in version (going from older to newer)

I'm not sure what the problem is, or even what to search for.  I would appreciate any guidance or help you can offer.

(edit: Digging a bit more, I discovered something is happening with matplotlib.  if I put print statments before and after the figure() command in twopoint_file, only the first one prints.  Calling this function directly from a python interpreter (removing cherrypy from the equation) I get the following error:

> can't invoke "event" command: application has been destroyed while executing "event generate $w{{ThemeChanged}}"
>   procedure "ttk::ThemeChanged" line 6 invoked from within "ttk::ThemeChanged"

end edit)

I don't understand what this error means, and haven't had much luck searching.

Comment: Show all the code, not just the config file.

Comment: I currently have 19 different files of code for this project, what would be most helpful to see?

Comment: How about the main to start with.

Comment: updated question to show the main file, and the relevant code from one case where my issue occurs.

Comment: How long does the process run? Is the server slower than your machine and it timeouts?

Comment: Typically the process only takes 1-2 seconds. On the machine where things aren't working properly, the process finishes the first time in about 2 seconds, but the second time I try to run it, it never finishes.

Comment: Although I do not see how the asker might be using Tk (Tkinter? IDLE?), the `ttk::ThemeChanged` error is a Tk bug: https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/info/310c74ecf440

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I got the same problem which I fixed by changing backend in Matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("qt4agg")
```